# conversion of dataframe obtained from aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Existing Dataframe :

```
                PushedDate                ID_number
                   amin         amax    
index           
7874            2022-02-18  2022-02-22       7874
4979            2021-10-06  2021-10-11       4979
```

I am looking for the dataframe , where i call use amin and amax as seperate columns :

```
               PushedDate_min   PushedDate_max   ID_number  
index           
7874            2022-02-18        2022-02-22         7874
4979            2021-10-06        2021-10-11         4979
```

Existing dataframe was obtained using below code :

```
aa = df.groupby(['ID_number']).agg({'PushedDate': [np.min, np.max]})
aa[aa.index.name] = aa.index 
aa.index.names = ['index']  # renaming the index
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can do:

```
aa = df.groupby(['ID_number']).agg({'PushedDate': [np.min, np.max]})
aa.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in aa.columns]
aa = aa.reset_index()
```